# How to make a unique token or ID for every Android Phone and where to save it?

Tags: android, security

I'm, working on a security scenario for an Android Application to prevent sending unwanted/spam or multi-requests by users.

These users are unregistered and as you know one way to detect them is by checking the IP addresses but the problem is that the public IP Addresses will change. Users can turn On/Off the modem (as an example) to get the new public IP Address or can install/uninstall the app to refresh everything and start sending unwanted requests to the server.

I want to make something like a token and store it on the phone that it will send with their request and on the server-side, we can detect which these requests come from which phone/user and handle the security issues.

This token or ID must have these features:

1. Access to it (deleting) should be impossible or hard for normal people (not for
   hackers, I know it's impossible)
2. If the app has been uninstalled/installed, Android OS doesn't remove
   it

Is it possible?

Is there a better solution to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

The Android developer docs have a good [article](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids) on available user IDs. Getting the second property will be difficult because Android has been pushing for resettable IDs for user privacy. The firebase installation ID (FID) is close, but you don't get #2. You can also use SafetyNet APIs to see if the app is genuine and then build rate limiting in the client or server side.